# timeout limit for holding exit status from system in perl/python

Tags: python, linux, perl, devops, nohup

I have a simple perl script that calls another python script to do the deployment of a server in cloud .

I capture the exit status of the deployment inside perl to take any further action after success/failure setup.

It's like:

```
$cmdret = system("python script.py ARG1 ARG2");
```

Here the python script runs for 3hrs to 7 hrs.

The problem here is that, irrespective of the success or failure return status, the system receive a Signal HUP at this step randomly even if the process is running in backened and breaks the steps further.

So  does anyone know, if there is any time limit for holding the return status from the system which leads to sending Hangup Signal?

Inside the python script `script.py`, pexpect is used execute scripts remotely:

```
doSsh(User,Passwd,Name,'cd '+OutputDir+';python host-bringup.py setup')
doSsh(User,Passwd,Name,'cd '+OpsHome+'/ops/hlevel;python  dshost.py start')
....
```

And `doSsh` is a `pexpect` subroutine:

```
def doSsh(user,password,host,command):
    try:
        child =  pexpect.spawn("ssh  -o ServerAliveInterval=100 -n %s@%s '%s'" % (user,host,command),logfile=sys.stdout,timeout=None)
        i = child.expect(['password:', r'\(yes\/no\)',r'.*password for paasusr: ',r'.*[$#] ',pexpect.EOF])
        if i == 0:
                child.sendline(password)
        elif i == 1:
                child.sendline("yes")
                child.expect("password:")
                child.sendline(password)
        data = child.read()
        print data
        child.close()
        return True
    except Exception as error:
        print error
        return False
```

This first `doSsh` execution takes `~6` hours and this session is killed after few hours of execution with the message :  `Signal HUP caught; exiting`but
the execution `python host-bringup.py setup` still runs in the remote host.

So in the local system, the next `doSsh` never runs and also the rest steps inside the perl script never continue.

Comment: The perldoc page for system discusses signal handling. Do "perldoc -f system" from your command line. Also, note that signal handling can behave quite differently on different *nix variants so you should probably note what OS you are using.

Comment: btw, no need to invoke a shell. `$cmdret = system("python", "script.py", " ARG1", "ARG2");`

Answer (score 2):

SIGHUP is sent when the terminal disconnects. When you want to create a process that's not tied to the terminal, you [daemonize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Daemon::Daemonize) it.

---

Note that `nohup` doesn't deamonize.

```
$ nohup perl -e'system "ps", "-o", "pid,ppid,sid,cmd"'
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'

$ cat nohup.out
  PID  PPID   SID CMD
21300 21299 21300 -bash
21504 21300 21300 perl -esystem "ps", "-o", "pid,ppid,sid,cmd"
21505 21504 21300 ps -o pid,ppid,sid,cmd
```

As you can see,

1. `perl`'s PPID is that of the program that launched it.
2. `perl`'s SID is that of the program that launched it.

Since the session hasn't changed, the terminal will send SIGHUP to `perl` when it disconnects as normal.

That said, `nohup` changes how `perl`'s handles SIGHUP by causing it to be ignored.

```
$ perl -e'system "kill", "-HUP", "$$"; print "SIGHUP was ignored\n"'
Hangup

$ echo $?
129

$ nohup perl -e'system "kill", "-HUP", "$$"; print "SIGHUP was ignored\n"'
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'

$ echo $?
0

$ tail -n 1 nohup.out
SIGHUP was ignored
```

If `perl` is killed by the signal, it's because something changed how `perl` handles SIGHUP.

So, either daemonize the process, or have `perl` ignore use SIGHUP (e.g. by using `nohup`). But if you use `nohup`, don't re-enable the default SIGHUP behaviour!

Comment: That's what the definition says. But in my case the perl script is already daemonized and still I receives the SIGHUP.

Comment: Using the module to which I linked?

Comment: Not using that module. There is a master script that calls a series of scripts one after another as a backend service by taking the exit status of previous one.

Comment: The reason I asked is that you say the script is daemonized, but I'm not sure you even know what the means. It's obviously NOT daemonized if the master collects its exit status, but maybe you meant the master script is daemonized?

Comment: The master script is running with nohup.

Comment: Yes thats correct, but 99% of the time HUP signal comes during execution of the above said line.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to make your perl program ignore the HUP signal, you likely just need to set the HUP entry of the $SIG global signal handler hash:

```
$SIG{ 'HUP' } = 'IGNORE';
```

for gory details, see

```
perldoc perlipc
```